# How to detect and handle write timeout in CXF

Tags: java, sockets, cxf

Encountered a strange situation today, my Java-based CXF client was hung writing to a remote socket.

Here's an abbreviated stack trace showing the process was blocked writing to a CXF-based JAX-WS interface:

```
java.net.SocketOutputStream.socketWrite0
java.net.SocketOutputStream.socketWrite
...
org.apache.cxf.io.AbstractWrappedOutputStream.write
org.apache.cxf.io.AbstractThresholdOutputStream.write
...
org.apache.cxf.jaxws.JaxWsClientProxy.invoke
com.sun.proxy.$Proxy143.getAllBusLmp
name.willdarby.trading.pjmService.PjmUpdateChecker.load5MinBus
```

A netstat showed the following, illustrating the socket is connected and write buffer is full:

```
Proto Recv-Q Send-Q Local Address               Foreign Address             State
tcp      482 182000 ip-xxx.xxx-xxx-xxx.ip.:41368 xxx.xxx.com:https    ESTABLISHED
```

So as I understand, the OS thought the socket was still alive, which is why the write blocked. It was in this state for at least 45 minutes.
I would like to detect these blocked writes after 5 minutes and reset the socket. Is there any way to do this with CXF (currently using version 3.1.4)?

Answer (score 1):

You can stablish a timeout and CXF will abort the connection.

```
Client client = ClientProxy.getClient(proxy);
HTTPConduit http = (HTTPConduit) client.getConduit();
HTTPClientPolicy httpClientPolicy = new HTTPClientPolicy();
httpClientPolicy.setConnectionTimeout(30000); // 30 seconds
httpClientPolicy.setReceiveTimeout(300000);  //5 minutes
http.setClient(httpClientPolicy);
```

The complete list of parameters is [here](http://cxf.apache.org/docs/client-http-transport-including-ssl-support.html).  0 means no timeout.

I am not sure if it will work for you because default connection timeout is `30` seconds and receive timeout is `60` seconds, so it should have been aborted.

Comment: Not in this case because it is blocked on a write rather than a read or connect. Those timeouts are set by default. I changed to an async connection with SO_KEEPALIVE. Not perfect, but should timeout based on the system keepalive period

Comment: I have never used async client. Reading documentation seems your solution probably will work. First, I guess you will have to lower the timeout of SO_KEEPALIVE from the default value of 2 hours. Post the answer if It works!